# pylucene unresolved reference when importing

Tags: pylucene

I have already installed JCC 2.23 and pylucene 6.4.1. However, when I open the sample of pylucene, there are always some errors just as [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijpRk.png). My Java version is 1.8 and I am using Mac OS X.

Comment: I have restarted pycharm for many times, but it doesn't work

Comment: I cannot enter images here, so please click the link to see the error.